# How to write down presentation of R-Modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, representation-theory, exact-sequence

For the following modules I should give presentations by generators & relations (finitely many each if possible):

- The $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Q}$
- The $\mathbb{C}[X]$-module $\mathbb{C}^4$, where for the standard $\mathbb{C}$-basis $e_1,...,e_4$ of $\mathbb{C}^4$ we have

$$X*e_1 = 0, X*e_2 = e_1, X*e_3 = 0\  \text{and} \ X*e_4 = e_3$$

- The $\mathbb{C}[X_1,X_2,...]$-module $\mathbb{C}$, where $X_i*z = 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and for all $i \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$

I see that $\mathbb{Q}$ cannot be generated by finitely many elements as an abelian group resp. $\mathbb{Z}$-module

I also think that 
 $$X*e_1 = 0, \ X^2*e_2 = X*e_1 = 0, X*e_3 = 0\  \text{and} \ X^2*e_4 = X*e_3 = 0$$
can be seen as the relations I need in the second one.
How do i write this down explicitly? As far as I know, a representation should be of the form of an exact sequence $$ R^{(J)} \xrightarrow{\phi_1} R^{(I)} \xrightarrow{\phi_2} M$$

However, I struggle with how to write it in this form.

Edit: What I've tried so far is the following for the first problem

Let $\mathbb{P}$ denote the set of prime numbers,

$\phi_1\colon \oplus_{p_i \in \mathbb{P}}\mathbb{Z}\to \oplus_{p_i \in \mathbb{P}}\mathbb{Z}$,       $e_{p_i} \mapsto p_i*e_{p_i}-p_{i+1} * e_{p_{i+1}}$

$\phi_2\colon \oplus_{p_i \in \mathbb{P}}\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Q}$, $e_{p_i} \mapsto 1/{p_i}$

The set of inverted primes generates $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\phi_2 \circ \phi_1 = 0$. Am I on the right path here?

Comment: You need to write up what you have tried. To find a presentation of an $R$-module $M$, you need to find a set of generators $S$, which gives you a surjective map $\phi\colon R^{\oplus S}\to M$. Then you need to determine the kernel $\ker\phi$, and find a set of generators of this kernel. Here is a hint: for $\mathbb Q$, the set of inverses of primes is a set of generator.

Comment: You need to [write those efforts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/) directly in the main post, which makes others better understand where you get stuck and help you more efficiently.

Comment: @Yai0Phah Small comment, I think you'd need reciprocals of prime powers, otherwise the $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule generated by reciprocals of primes would be the elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ with square-free denominators.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thanks. You are correct. We need to invert prime powers too.